# Htmlunit Javascript Button/Link

Tags: java, javascript, button, htmlunit

I am trying to find the link/button for a specific source. I have already managed to assign a button using the 'form' properties, however the new button I am trying to press does not have a form. Below is the HTML source code for the javascript button:

```
<span class="followButtonActions" id=".reactRoot[0].[0].[1].[2].{userprofile0001}.[1].[1].   [1].[1]">
    <a class="Button FollowButton followButtonFollow" role="button" href="javascript:;" id=".reactRoot[0].[0].[1].[2].{userprofile0001}.[1].[1].[1].[1].0">
        <span id=".reactRoot[0].[0].[1].[2].{userprofile0001}.[1].[1].[1].[1].0.[0]">
        <span id=".reactRoot[0].[0].[1].[2].{userprofile0001}.[1].[1].[1].[1].0.[0].[0]">Follow</span>    </span>
    </a>
</span>
```

So far I been trying to use the class to identify the element, however I have been unsuccessful in finding the link/button on page. 
I have been trying to use htmlAnchor however that didn't work so I switched to DOM ELEMENT.
Below is my current code for finding the button/link which results: java.lang.NullPointerException.

```
final DomElement myAnchor = page3.getFirstByXPath("//span[@class='followButtonActions']");
final HtmlPage newPage = myAnchor.click();
```

I have also tried the following which results in: java.lang.NullPointerException.

```
    final HtmlSubmitInput button = page.getFirstByXPath("//class[@id='.reactRoot[0].[0].[1].[2].{userprofile0001}.[1].[1].[1].[1].0']");
    final HtmlPage newPage = button.click();
```

I have got to a point where I am trying almost everything! In laymans terms, I am trying to assign the javascript link to a button which can then be pressed. My approach was to somehow link the 'Button FollowButton followButtonFollow' to a button which can be clicked. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get that anchor tag, you should use the XPath:

```
//a[@id='.reactRoot[0].[0].[1].[2].{userprofile0001}.[1].[1].[1].[1].0']
```

Check the demo code below:

```
import java.net.URL;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;
public class HtmlUnitAnchorExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String html = "<html><head><title>HTMLUNIT TEST</title></head><body>" +
                "" +
                "<span class=\"followButtonActions\" id=\".reactRoot[0].[0].[1].[2].{userprofile0001}.[1].[1].   [1].[1]\"> "+
                " <a class=\"Button FollowButton followButtonFollow\" role=\"button\" href=\"javascript:;\" id=\".reactRoot[0].[0].[1].[2].{userprofile0001}.[1].[1].[1].[1].0\"> "+
                "     <span id=\".reactRoot[0].[0].[1].[2].{userprofile0001}.[1].[1].[1].[1].0.[0]\"> "+
                "     <span id=\".reactRoot[0].[0].[1].[2].{userprofile0001}.[1].[1].[1].[1].0.[0].[0]\">Follow</span>    </span> "+
                " </a> "+
                "</span>" +
                "</body></html>";

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page = HTMLParser.parseHtml(new StringWebResponse(html, new URL("http://example.com")), client.getCurrentWindow());
        System.out.println("Page title: "+page.getTitleText());

        final HtmlAnchor myAnchor = page.getFirstByXPath("//a[@id='.reactRoot[0].[0].[1].[2].{userprofile0001}.[1].[1].[1].[1].0']");
        System.out.println("Anchor found: "+myAnchor );
        final HtmlPage newPage = myAnchor .click();
        System.out.println("newPage: "+newPage);

        client.closeAllWindows();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have applied your code, however my anchor printed as NULL. For some reason when I view the source, I can view the <space class=/"follo....> however, when I print the page using page.asXml(), I cannot view the <span class...> etc. Would you be able to suggest any ideas?

Comment: Do a `webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10 * 1000);` before calling `page.asXml()`. From what you say, the source page seems to create thos elements (you posted) by javascript. Is that so?